# how to enforce the redelivery for un acknowledge jms message

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel

I read on : http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074123/java-web-development/transaction-and-redelivery-in-jms.html?page=2

"Generally, acknowledging a particular message acknowledges all prior messages the session receives" ( in Client acknowledgement mode )

"Message redelivery is not automatic, but messages are redelivered under certain circumstances"

My questions :

1. how can I ensure there is a new session every time I recive a message (but reuse the connection)?
2. how to enforce the redelivery  for un acknowledge message ?

Im using this configration :

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory"
            lazy-init="true">
            <property name="queueManager" value="${queueManager}" />
            <property name="hostName" value="${hostName}" />
            <property name="transportType" value="${transportType}" />
            <property name="port" value="${port}" />
            <property name="channel" value="${channel}" />
            <property name="SSLCipherSuite" value="${SSLCipherSuite}" />
      </bean>
<bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="10"/>
    <property name="maximumActive" value="100"/>
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>
<bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="transacted" value="false"/>
 </bean>

<bean id="mqNonJmsDestRes" class="calypsox.tk.util.NonJmsMQQueueDestinationResolver" />

<bean id="jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
      <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig" />
       <property name="acknowledgementModeName" value="CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE" />
       <property name="destinationResolver" ref="mqNonJmsDestRes" />
 </bean>
```

and I use camel processor as endpoint bean as singleton

Answer (score 0):

That article you referenced is from 2002.  All of the MQ based systems have received a lot of work since then.  On your AMQ PooledConnectionFactory there are settings to control how long your connections last before they are destroyed and what you should do if you encounter an error.  I recommend reading into some of the newer documentation since there has been a lot of changes in the last 14 years.  So some things have become much easier.

You can also check into the exceptionListener on "org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent"  to configure how to manage exceptions and even write your own if the current options don't suit your needs.

Comment: thank you . some questions please : I understand that the PooledConnectionFactory /cachedConnectionFactory cache connections and sessions (and optionally receivers/producers).So does a new session is being created for every new message or not ? if not - I read that acknowledge is for all messages in the session - very bad ... I need a new session for every message .. but in this case how sessions can be pooled ? and also - if the connection is one for all sessions , un acknowledge messages wil not be delivered until I restart my application , no ? Also not good .

Comment: If we are talking specifically about the ActiveMQ Pooled Connection Factory.  I have used fairly recently.  The sessions are configured per each connection.  Meaning if you have an error (IE: timeout or transaction failure"  you can configure the factory to destroy and recreate the connection on an error.  When you destroy the connection the sessions will be destroyed along with it and then recreated.  Things can get a bit tricky to configure when you get more complicated transaction settings, but the basis is if you destroy the connection you also destroy the associated sessions.

Comment: yes but does undeliver messages will be delivar while the connection has not restarted (connection being pooled and not close for every message)? if not - I have do trigger on my application code a connection restart every some logic time , no ?

Comment: So to clarify.  You want to make sure that when a message receives an exception you want the ActiveMQ broker to redeliver the message right away.  This will be the case as long as you destroy the connection the message was using so the broker is not waiting for retry attempts and it will automatically redeliver your message